# Can docker containers be run on live web servers?

Tags: heroku, docker

I read that heroku uses what they call cedar containers in their infrastructure which allows developers to use containerisation in their apps hosted on heroku. If I'm not mistaken that is, I'm new to all this.

Is is possible to run docker containers on web servers and integrate them as part of your website? Or at least, come up with a method of converting docker containers into Cedar containers or something similar which are compatible with the web server?

On your own private server I see no reason why you couldn't do this, but when it comes to commercial web hosting services, where does this stand?

Comment: If heroku wants to survive, it will accommodate docker -- not the other way around.    Docker can run on any x64 server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not running "docker on web server", but running "docker with web server".
I mean, you supposed to package your app into the docker with some kind of web server.

After it, you can call your app in this container as regular web site. Also, you can host this container in some docker host (for example, [docker cloud](https://cloud.docker.com/app/evgenylu/dashboard/onboarding/cloud-registry), [sloppy.io](https://sloppy.io/),...)

As for heroku, may be you'll find [this helpful](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime)